# Multiple Inheritance: same variable name

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

```
class A
{
   protected:
    string word;
};

class B
{
   protected:
    string word;
};

class Derived: public A, public B
{

};
```

How would the accessibility of the variable `word` be affected in `Derived`? How would I resolve it?

Comment: Note that apart from the good answers below, it is always a good policy to avoid this kind of name clashes as much as possible.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It will be ambiguous, and you'll get a compilation error saying that.

You'll need to use the right scope to use it:

```
 class Derived: public A, public B
{
    Derived()
    {
        A::word = "A!";
        B::word = "B!!";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use the `using` keyword to tell the compiler which version to use:

```
class Derived : public A, public B
{
protected:
    using A::word;
};
```

This tells the compiler that the `Derived` class has a protected member `word`, which will be an alias to `A::word`. Then whenever you use the unqualified identifier `word` in the `Derived` class, it will mean `A::word`. If you want to use `B::word` you have to fully qualify the scope.

Comment: Don't you have to say what has to be "used" for A::word? or is `using A::word` alone really enough?

Comment: @Zaibis That's enough really, it makes `Derived::word` an alias of `A::word`, basically.

Comment: I'm beliving you, I just asked as I'm not that used to c++ as I'm with C. ;)

Comment: `using A::word` in a full sentence would be: "Compiler, when I talk about `word` in the following clause, I really mean `A::word`"

Answer (score 6):

Your class `Derived` will have two variables, `B::word` and `A::word` Outside of `Derived` you can access them like this (if you change their access to public):

```
Derived c;
c.A::word = "hi";
c.B::word = "happy";
```

Attempting to access `c.word` will lead to an **error**, since there is no field with the name `word`, but only A::word and B::word.

Inside `Derived` they behave like regular fields, again, with the names `A::var` and `B::var` also mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

When accessing `word` in the class of `Derived`, you had to declare

```
class Derived: public A, public B
{
    Derived()
    {
       A::word = X;
       //or
       B::word = x;
    }
};
```