# syntax for overriding function in multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

```
class A
{
   protected:
    void func1() //DO I need to call this virtual?
};

class B
{
   protected:
    void func1() //and this one as well?
};

class Derived: public A, public B
{
    public:

    //here define func1 where in the code there is
    //if(statement) {B::func1()} else {A::func1()}
};
```

how do you override the func1? or can you just define it

```
class Derived: public A, public B
{
    public:

    void func1()
};
```

without any virtual or override? I don't understand the accessibility. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this almost the same Question as you asked some minutes before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763903/multiple-inheritance-same-variable-name

Comment: Yes it is, but it was for a variable not a function. This question asks for overriding the function.

Comment: But anyway I don't get your question? you can't use a if statement in a class definition, can you?

Comment: hmm why?? Depending on the condition or state, we can call a func1 from a or func1 from b right? @Zaibis

Comment: And sorry for spamming, but If you are working much with such cases, you should look up for the "Diamond problem" as your cases are getting close to it. Using `virtual` wouldn't help you here (afaik) as it just tells the base class or derived class has to be used, but as the base classes have both the method, I would guess it could even be erroneous to use virtual. (But please correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: Thank you for your input. Now it makes sense to me to see it erroneous to use virtual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leonard Lie,

to override you can simply declare the function with the same name, to achieve the functionality in the comments in the code you need a variable being passed to Derived func1()

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
   protected:
    void func1()    {   cout << "class A\n";    } //DO I need to call this virtual?
};

class B
{
   protected:
    void func1()    {   cout << "class B\n";    } //and this one as well?
};

class Derived: public A, public B
{
    public:

    //here define func1 where in the code there is
    //if(statement) {B::func1()} else {A::func1()}
    void func1(bool select = true)
    {
        if (select == true)
        {
            A::func1();
        }
        else
        {
            B::func1();
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
   Derived d;
   d.func1();          //returns default value based on select being true
   d.func1(true);      //returns value based on select being set to true
   d.func1(false);     // returns value base on select being set to false
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

This should do what you are looking for,  I have used a boolean as there are only 2 possible versions, but you could use an `enum` or `int` to suit a case with more options.